# Trouble with .equals() and ==

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with these if statements and can't figure out the problem:

1. If I try changing them to a nested if, else if format I get a compiler error saying "else" with no if statement.
2. The if statements don't even work, as you can see from the ouput below they all run even when the strings aren't equal.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
if (labelArray[0] == e.getSource() && myAppliance.size() >= 1) {
    if (myAppliance.get(0).getClass().getName().toUpperCase().equals("CLOCK")); {
        System.out.println(options[0]);
        System.out.println(myAppliance.get(0).getClass().getName());
        infoBox((myAppliance.get(0).toString()),"Info");
    }
    if (myAppliance.get(0).getClass().getName().toUpperCase().equals("LAMP")); //"Clock", "Lamp", "Television"
    {
        System.out.println(options[1]);
        System.out.println(myAppliance.get(0).getClass().getName());
        infoBox((myAppliance.get(0).toString()),"Info");
    }
    if (myAppliance.get(0).getClass().getName().toUpperCase().equals("TELEVISION")); {
        System.out.println(options[2]);
        System.out.println(myAppliance.get(0).getClass().getName());
        infoBox((myAppliance.get(0).toString()),"Info");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Clock
Clock
Lamp
Clock
Television
Clock
```

Comment: instead of `toUpperCase` you can use `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: I still don't understand why you close the `if` statements using a semicolon `;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `;` at the end of the lines with the `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `;` from immediate after if statements, compilers take them as **statements** and it defeats the purpose of using `if` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ifs work on the next statement they can take, so they'll run on the next line or treat a block enclosed on curly braces as a statement. By writing `;` after the if, it's basically using an empty statement, then just proceeding to execute your block of code regardless.

Just remove the `;` and it should work.